# Dynamic link visualization between polygons and line with Geometry Generator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator, qgis-expression

Let's say we have 4 polygons in a polygon layer called 'Flaeche':

- Polygon A
- Polygon B
- Polygon C
- Polygon D

The attribute table of this polygon layer contains 3 columns called 'Name', 'Einzelflaeche', and 'Haltung'.

We also have a line layer called 'Rohr'. The related attribute table contains 2 columns called 'Name' and 'Kanalart'. This layer contains 1 object.

Using the Geometry Generator, I want to draw a colored line based on the 'Kanalart' value of the line layer, starting from the A polygon up to the line layer, passing through each centroid of the polygons.

The links between the objects are as follows:

- For each polygon and for the line, there is a Name in the 'Name' field.
- For the A polygon, the 'Einzelflaeche' field contains the 'Name' value of the B Polygon.
- For the B polygon, the 'Einzelflaeche' field contains the 'Name' value of the C Polygon.
- For the C polygon, the 'Einzelflaeche' field contains the 'Name' value of the D Polygon.
- For the D polygon, the 'Einzelflaeche' field has a NULL value. The 'Name' value of the line layer is written in the 'Haltung' column for the D polygon.

This structure is illustrated in the example given below:
[image]

The reason I want to use the Geometry Generator is that I want to dynamically see the link between the objects. Note that the number of polygons could be higher or lower than 4. However, the endpoint is always a line from the 'Rohr' layer.

I have made several attempts using the collect(), union(), and make_line() expressions, with unique or successive styles, but without success. My best result was obtained by creating a style for the connection between the line and the D polygon, and another style for the link between the A, B, C, and D polygons. The problem was that I did not find a way to apply a color to this last style based on the 'Kanalart' field. Therefore, I think the best approach would be to write one or more expressions in a unique Geometry Generator, which would make the coloring of the dynamic line easier.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I think its better to write little plugin to construct connection line you need. You have to  connect both layers change signals (layerModified) to your algoritm. This way connection line will be dynamically generated.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately I'm not skilled enough to be able to create a plugin that executes what I want... But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal dataset, eg as inlined geojson?